# ProgressDialog keeps on showing despite being cancelled and hidden

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

Right now I'm simulating the showing of a ProgressDialog for an event that is expected to take several seconds.

I'm doing it this way:

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.calendar_load));
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
progressDialog.show();
Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(6000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        progressDialog.cancel();
                        progressDialog.hide();
```

But even though I've checked in debug that the progressDialog.cancel() and progressDialog.hide() execute the dialog just keeps on showing apparently in an indefinite way.

What could be causing such behavior?

PROBLEM SOLVED: Thanks to everyone who has answered/commented, it looks like an emulator bug (indeed it has also worked some times on emulator).

Comment: can you upload full your code. i try your code and it's work

Answer (score 2):

Call `progressDialog.dismiss();`

Comment: thanks for answering, but it doesn't work. It stays the same.

Comment: try remove the 3rd line , progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

Comment: @MdBasha, thanks for your attention, but it also doesn't work.

Comment: I tried your code and it works properly, the progress dialog dismissed, but i have a little doubt that you forget to call t.start();, so all the code on the the run() method is not executed.

Comment: I called t.start(), maybe it's an emulator bug. I'll check on physical device.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this snippet?

```
progressDialog.show();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        while (progressDialog.getProgress() <= progressDialog.getMax()) {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                            handle.sendMessage(handle.obtainMessage());
                            if (progressDialog.getProgress() == progressDialog.getMax()) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();

            Handler handle = new Handler() {
                    @Override
                    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                        super.handleMessage(msg);
                        progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(1);
                    }
            };
```